# Value restriction - The value has been inferred to have generic type

Tags: f#, polymorphism, value-restriction

Give the following definition

```
let fn (id: int) (_:string) = id
```

I can create a partially applied function

```
let fnPartial = fn 1
```

However changing the type of `_` to a non sealed type like `IEnumerable`

```
let fn (id: int) (_:IEnumerable) = id
```

Causes a compilation error

> Value restriction. The value 'fnPartial' has been inferred to have
>   generic type
>       val fnPartial : ('_a -> int) when '_a :> IEnumerable     Either make the arguments to 'fnPartial' explicit or, if you do not intend
>   for it to be generic, add a type annotation. (using built-in F#
>   compiler)

[A bug was raised](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/6509) but closed with the following response

> Yes this is by design - IEnumerable is not sealed where string is, and
>   this causes the value restriction to trigger

The work around is to add a type annotation

```
let fn (id: int) (_:IEnumerable ) = id
let fnPartial<'a> = fn 1
```

Can someone explain

1. Whats the crux of the issue
2. How does adding a type annotation fix the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is that *values* are not allowed to be generic in F#. When you partially apply a *function* the result is a *value*.

In order to make the left hand side of a binding (or assignment) a function, you must define a parameter on the left hand side.

The error you're getting is a result of `IEnumerable` not being specific enough for the *value* to be completely defined. Given `IEnumerable` you do not know what you're iterating over, and therefore the compiler cannot determine a proper type for the value.

The answers to your question then are as follows:

1. The crux is the issue is that a value cannot be generic
2. Adding the type definition lets the compiler know that this is not a value, but rather is a function, or something which is allowed to be generic.

Here is the relevant MSDN Docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/dd233183(v=vs.100)#value-restriction